# How to specify default module in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

By default Zend Framework specifies "default" module is the default module of application. Now I want my "frontend" module is the default module in my app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config file

```
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "frontend"
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller

### Update

You cannot "rename" the default module. If you're only interested in changing the URL structure, use custom routes. For example

```
resources.router.routes.frontend.route = "frontend/:controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.frontend.defaults.module = "default"
```

Comment: Does it necessary to change the configurations in the application/Bootstrap.php file too? How about the prefixes of classes in each module?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot "rename" the default module. I'll update my answer with what I think you're after

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (application.ini):

```
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "yourModule"
resources.modules[] = ""
```